# Image Url is not valid in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to store the Url of Image from Firebase Storage to Real-time database, and then load the Url by Picasso library, but the image is stored but incorrect formate, all other images are loading but one child with name postimage is not loading because it's URL is not correct.
I only need to know that this code is correct with androidx because I am using androidx.
and rest of things are working properly something is wrong with this code.

Loading Image url from Storage to Realtime database Code:

````
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
               if (task.isSuccessful())
               {  filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                       final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                       postImageUri = downloadUrl;
                   }

               });
                  PostImage = postImageUri;
                   // downloadUrl = task.getResult().getUploadSessionUri().toString();
//                   final String downloadUrl = filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
//                   postImageUri = downloadUrl;
                 // downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                   Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Image Uploaded Successfully To Storage!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   SavingPostInformationToDatabase( );
               }
               else
                   {
                       String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                       Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error! " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
            }
        });```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue but later on, I solved... as you guys can see that I am using filePath.getDownload method and there I am getting image Uri to store in the realtime database through the variable postImagUri..so as long as the variable inside filePath.getDownload it has the image link properly but as far we use that variable outside that filePath.getDownload it gives a null value that is inappropriate.
So simply I cut my method SavingPostInformationToDatabase( ); and pasted it inside filePath.getDownload Cause the variable that stores image link I was using in SavingPostInformationToDatabase( ); method.
SavingPostInformationToDatabase( ); is a method that stores values to realtime database using HashMap method.